# How can I pull and show dynamic data with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I made a program with functions to show a bunch of random numbers every x number of seconds. Now, instead of calling the Math.random method to return this lot of random "data", I need to pull numbers from a website, database, or cloud document and show this dynamic data. I'm not very knowledgeable on pulling data from outside sources, so how can I go about doing this?

Comment: [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: Do you want to display numbers from a specific source, or do you just need them for a random seed?

Comment: @SebastianSchmied I need to display numbers from a specific source.

Comment: Is it an outside source, or would it be created by yourself?

Comment: @SebastianSchmied Just as an example, I would like to display the current weather from weather.com. I would not have access to changing these numbers myself, and I need to update the current temperature as weather.com updates their numbers.

Comment: There are services for just that: https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/

They provide the data in an easily parsable format. It's a broad field, see their documentation: https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs#getting_started

Answer (score 0):

Make a backend script (PHP) to generate a random number say it is getRandomnumber.php .
you can use an AJAX call to get random numbers:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "getRandomnumber.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText); //you will get a random number in console
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Please stop answering overly broad questions.